# Master of Flame (Paragon Path) and Flaming Weapon

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, weapons, paragon-path

Master of Flame paragon path has a level 12 Utility Power called Burning Transformation.

> **Burning Transformation** - You transform into a creature of fire until the end of the encounter. While in this form you gain the following benefits and limitations: You are insubistantial, you can shift 1 square as a minor action, you are immune to fire, you gain a +5 power bonus to damage rolls with arcane fire attacks, *and you cannot use any attack power without the Fire keyword.* Aditionally, whenever an enemy hits you with a melee attack, it takes fire damage equal to 5 + your Intelligence modifier.

That said, Could a Swordmage wielding a Flaming Bastard Sword (with the Fire damage activated)use any Arcane Attack Power, for example: Sword Burst, as a power with the Fire keyword? In short, while Burning Transformation is active you can use any offensive Arcane attack power because a Flaming Weapon grants them the Fire keyword?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

A Weapon of Summer adds 3 fire damage to your rolls. This means that your swordmage is A-OK to use regular powers (that have damage rolls) wielding this weapon as they become fire powers.

[From the Rules Compendium (pg 115):](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8164/does-lasting-frost-affect-the-damage-dealt-by-a-frost-weapon/8166#8166)

> If a power gains or loses damage types, the power gains the keywords for any damage types that are added, and it loses the keywords for any damage types that are removed.

A Flaming Weapon does not work, as an errata changed the it so that it only modifes *untyped* damage, and Sword Burst is Force.